# Deploying Node JS app to Google cloud 500 server error

Tags: node.js, express, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I am deploying my Node js App to Google Cloud. After deploying the application i got 500 server error.
I further check out the logs than i got

```
Error: Cannot find module './routes/userRoute'
 Require stack:
2021-03-23 13:04:34   - /workspace/server.js
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
2021-03-23 13:04:34      at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/server.js:6:19)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-03-23 13:04:34 default[20210323t183158]      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-03-23 13:04:34       at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
2021-03-23 13:04:34       code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-03-23 13:04:34    requireStack: [ '/workspace/server.js' ]
2021-03-23 13:04:34  }
```

Even though the app is running fine locally and this module userRoute is included in server.js but still i am getting this error

app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs14
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "backend of our react app",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.10",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^7.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^6.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

Please help me resolve the problem

Comment: I would start with checking `.gcloudignore` file in your deployment directory, if this was not included there by mistake. Please check the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) - if this is not the reason please add little more info about the module...

Comment: `.gcloudignore`  is present in my deployment directory with `node_modules` in it to ignore node modules , further the module which it can't find is present in the directory and app is running well on localhost but gcloud is not able to find it and i don't know why

Comment: is this `routes` folder outside `workspace` folder? can you show folders structure?

Comment: routes folder in in same directory as server.js and app.yaml

Comment: It's hard to say with those details. How do you use this module? Can you show some parts of `server.js`?